# python defaultdict(list) IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, defaultdict

I am trying to use `defaultdict(list)` as,

```
dict = defaultdict(list)
dict['A'][1] = [1]
```

or

```
dict['A'][1] = list([1])
```

I got an error,

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

if I do

```
dict['A'][1].append(1)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am wondering what is the issue here.

Comment: What is list in dict = defaultdict(list)
 ?

Comment: Hint: what you're trying to do is basically `[][1] = [1]`. An empty list doesn't have a `1` index to assign to.

Comment: The issue: that is not how you assign an element to an inexistent index of a list. `list.append` is how it's done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some issues here:

1. You're using 1 for the index value while the default list you have start at index 0.
2. When you append, you don't need to specify the index.
3. And finally, it's not a good idea to declare a variable with the same name as a built-in type (`dict`, in this case) since that would usually result in unexpected behavior later on when you would use the built-in type.

Revised, your code would be:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d['A'].append(1)
>>> d['A']
[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't use `dict` as a name. Use something like `d` so you don't mask the built-in name `dict`.

Secondly, `d['A'][1] = list([1])` tries to access the index `1` *of an empty list* (the value you initialize the `defaultdict` with) and assign to it, that's a no-no.

You are probably looking for:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
d['A'].append(1)
```

Comment: what if the `1` in `d['A'][1]`, is a key and assign to it `[1]` as value, what should I do, so `d['A']` is a nested dict.

Comment: @daiyue Then use a `defaultdict(dict)`

Comment: It's a key? Then why do you initialize the `defaultdict` with a list and not a `dict`?